# Preprocessing sensor data with a time and value as x and y in Highcharts. Will an array within an array work?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to create a Highcharts line graph with temperature data from multiple sensors each posting results at different times. The data is stored in a MySQL database as id, location, temp, timestamp. Since each sensor will be generating data at unique times the x values will not line up. For this reason I am interested in supplying each Highcharts series with a x- value and y-value... something like:

```
series: [{ // Location 1
   name: 'Main Bedroom',
   data: time1, temperature1
```

I am starting with a single location (MainBDRm) to develop my code.
I am using the following query to get and store multiple rows of data.

```
$sql = "SELECT temp, reading_time FROM ASHP_SensorData WHERE location = 'MainBDRm' ORDER BY reading_time DESC LIMIT 5"; 

while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $sensor_data[] = $data;
{

$temperature1 = json_encode(array_reverse(array_column($sensor_data, 'temp')), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$time1        = json_encode(array_reverse(array_column($sensor_data, 'reading_time')), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

echo $temperature1 yields an array as  [76,75,73,71,70]
echo $time1 yields an array as          ["2021-12-19 17:07:13","2021-12-19 17:07:43","2021-12-19 17:08:13","2021-12-19 17:08:44","2021-12-19 17:09:14"]
```

I have confirmed that I can successfully produce a chart with

```
series: [{ // Location 1
    name: 'Main Bedroom',
    //yAxis: 0,
    //showInLegend: true,

    //data: temperature1,  // works
    data:[  // this works too
        ["2021-12-19 17:07:13", 76],
        ["2021-12-19 17:07:43", 75],
        ["2021-12-19 17:08:13", 73],
        ["2021-12-19 17:09:14", 71],
        ],
```

I would like to know if it is possible to use Json to preprocess the query results as a array in an array and use that as an input for the data: element with both the x & y values. Something like: ["2021-12-19 17:07:13", 76], ... , ["2021-12-19 17:09:14", 70]

I have tried

```
$stringToReturn = array();
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $sensor_data[] = $data;
    array_push($stringToReturn, $data);
}
echo json_encode($stringToReturn, $data);
```

which yields:

```
[{"reading_time":"2021-12-19 22:24:33","temp":"79.70"},{"reading_time":"2021-12-19 22:24:03","temp":"79.70"},{"reading_time":"2021-12-19 22:23:33","temp":"79.70"},{"reading_time":"2021-12-19 22:23:03","temp":"79.70"},{"reading_time":"2021-12-19 22:22:33","temp":"79.70"}]
```

but I am not sure how to use this in the Highcharts script, or if it is in a usable form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that Highcharts expects to get `x and y` values in the data array, not custom names as `"reading_time"` or `"temp"`, so you need to parse your data into the required format.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oe3j9fcp/

Or you can do it a few steps earlier: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pd32q7zo/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data